# Hiding UITabbar when scrolling in iOS

Tags: scroll, uitabbar

Hi i am trying to replicate A UItabbar being hidden and showing while scrolling much like how the pinterest and google + apps do it. I found a quick emulation on git hub by tony million https://github.com/tonymillion/ExpandingView . it works great but theres a problem and its huge for me. if you rapidly scroll up and down you will see a white bar at the bottom while the tab bar is hidden. if you scroll normally everything works fine. but as a programmer i don't want to worry about that white space on the bottom showing up. I searched around and noticed others were getting the same problem. if theres anyway this can be fix i would greatly appreciate it. thank you.